# Anyone been successful with SSO between SharePoint onprem and ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, auth0

I'm trying to establish SSO between SharePoint 2016 onprem and ASP.NET Core API but finding doco on this scenario has been difficult if not futile.

A summary of the 3 main use cases are as follows

1. Embedded SharePoint webpart needs to call into SharePoint restful services. I assume the SAML token associated with the user identity can be used here without any issue.
2. Embedded SharePoint webpart needs to call a custom ASP.NET Core API. The API then needs to call into SharePoint restful services.
3. Call is made from custom Angular web application or phone app into custom ASP.NET Core API. The API then needs to call into SharePoint restful services.

I'm thinking of using something like Auth0 to help get this up and running as fast as possible. However, are there any experts out there who could help we confirm

1. Is this is all in fact possible?
2. As SharePoint only supports SAML tokens and not JWT\OpenId Connect I'm assuming the custom web application and ASP.NET Core API would all need to support SAML tokens?
3. If you have used the likes of Okta or Auth0 before, could they be used to achieve this?
4. Are you aware of any doco covering these use cases?

Thanks heaps for any help or direction you could offer!

Comment: How are you authenticating your users? Do you have an authentication provider, like AD FS? When calling into SharePoint, do you need to impersonate the user, or would it be acceptable if a service account would do the work? Also, what exact extension model are you referring to with “embedded webpart”?

Comment: Hi @poke thanks for the reply. As mentioned in my post I'm using Auth0 to get things up and running. Obviously behind that can be ADFS or any Social authentication provider like facebook or google etc. In my case I have setup with an AD connector. I need to pass the token around as I cannot compromise the auditing capability of SharePoint by using a Service Account. Regarding the webparts, our system has been around since the first version of SharePoint so the webparts are your standard webparts which I cannot change.

Comment: did you get any solution?